# Listview item:align image at right of the list view item

Tags: android, listview

i'm creating a custom list item in and android list view. it's very simple,but we can't align image view at right center

PLz help me how we can align image at right center

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/star1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_company"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:textColor="#25383C"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_position"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_company"

    android:textColor="#25383C"
    android:singleLine="true"

    android:textSize="16dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_city"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_position"

    android:textColor="#25383C"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_state"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_city"

    android:textColor="#25383C"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Please suggest me ,How we can align image view at right center

Thank you in advance

Comment: `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` try adding this line to your ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for the `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/star1" />
```

You can also try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTextOuter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_company"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textColor="#25383C"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textColor="#25383C"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textColor="#25383C"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textColor="#25383C"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/star1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you Tamilan it's working fine and also we want to set textview at left of the image view

Comment: @BishnuKumar Use `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img" and android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for that textview

Comment: @BishnuKumar you can check my edit and also don't forget to accept my ans.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/star1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llTextOuter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_company"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textColor="#25383C"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textColor="#25383C"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textColor="#25383C"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_state"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textColor="#25383C"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

your imageview is aligned to right, if you want to center it vertically, you can use  android:layout_centerVertical="true"